# how to play audio or video from ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android, video-streaming, audio-streaming

how to play video or audio from

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
mp.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
pfd.close();
mp.setDisplay(holder);
mp.prepareAsync();
mp.start();
```

it showing error that unable to create media player.what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you realy want but, may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770760/1012234) answer can help you. 
Also read the original question to be sure tha it's the same problem you have.

Try this code:

```
 String hostname = "192.168.1.10";
int port = 8000;
Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

recorder.start();
```

Comment: ya i am sending audio file to server side by using parcel file descriptor but i could no be able to play by using parcel file descriptor wat is the reason?

Comment: Your code captures the audio and sends it through socket, but he wants to play it in the other side!